# Where is multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-3.4

I am porting a working application from Python 3.3 to 3.4 and have encountered a weird situation. The class multiprocessing.Process is not present in the download from python.org. Instead, in the multiprocessing.process module, I find a class multiprocessing.process.BaseProcess. The only trace of the old Process class that I can find is in the new multiprocessing.context module where multiprocessing.context.Process is basically a cover function for BaseProcess. None of this is mentioned in the documentation for Python 3.4. Can anyone tell me what is going on and possibly point me at some documentation.

Comment: It's still there - https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process

Comment: This is the joy of duck-typing. As long as it has the same interface, it shouldn't matter if they change the actual concrete class.

Comment: The docs talk about it, but it is missing in the code. As changes in the code are needed to use the new packaging, you can't call it duck typing. There are other undocumented changes as well. For instance multiprocessing.Queue is now multiprocessing.queues.Queue.

Comment: @Jonathan, it's still `multiprocessing.Queue` from an API perspective; calling `q = multiprocessing.Queue()` returns a `Queue` object. You're only going to have issues if you need the actual class object so you can sub-class it or use `isinstance` on it or something, in which case I do agree that the changes between 3.3 and 3.4 are disruptive.

Comment: @Jonathan Also, the "What's new" documentation for Python 3.4 [does mention](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/3.4.html#multiprocessing) there were changes to `multiprocessing`, and links to two bugs in the tracker that go into more detail on what changed and why. [This comment](http://bugs.python.org/issue18999#msg200507) mentions that they should probably document some of the refactoring of objects that occurred, but (obviously) that never happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Eclipse and PyDev you need to include 'multiprocessing' as a forced builtin for the python interpreter.

Comment: I actually did that, restarted, run code analysis and still get the issue. I am running Eclipse Oxygen with the latest PyDev.

Answer (score 1):

It's still there, it's just defined in a very different way:

`multiprocessing/__init__.py` now adds attributes to the top-level package like this:

```
#
# Copy stuff from default context
#

globals().update((name, getattr(context._default_context, name))
                 for name in context._default_context.__all__)
__all__ = context._default_context.__all__
```

So it's pulling `__all__` from `context._default_context`.

If you look in `context.py`, you can find a `Process` class:

```
#
# Type of default context -- underlying context can be set at most once
#

class Process(process.BaseProcess):
    _start_method = None
    @staticmethod
    def _Popen(process_obj):
        return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
```

And more concrete implementations are referenced and defined in there, too:

```
class ForkProcess(process.BaseProcess):
    _start_method = 'fork'
    @staticmethod
    def _Popen(process_obj):
        from .popen_fork import Popen
        return Popen(process_obj)

class SpawnProcess(process.BaseProcess):
    _start_method = 'spawn'
    @staticmethod
    def _Popen(process_obj):
        from .popen_spawn_posix import Popen
        return Popen(process_obj)

class ForkServerProcess(process.BaseProcess):
    _start_method = 'forkserver'
    @staticmethod
    def _Popen(process_obj):
        from .popen_forkserver import Popen
        return Popen(process_obj)

class ForkContext(BaseContext):
    _name = 'fork'
    Process = ForkProcess

class SpawnContext(BaseContext):
    _name = 'spawn'
    Process = SpawnProcess

class ForkServerContext(BaseContext):
    _name = 'forkserver'
    Process = ForkServerProcess
    def _check_available(self):
        from . import reduction
        if not reduction.HAVE_SEND_HANDLE:
            raise ValueError('forkserver start method not available')

_concrete_contexts = {
    'fork': ForkContext(),
    'spawn': SpawnContext(),
    'forkserver': ForkServerContext(),
}

_default_context = DefaultContext(_concrete_contexts['fork'])
```

the `__all__` for default context gets set a little later:

```
DefaultContext.__all__ = list(x for x in dir(DefaultContext) if x[0] != '_')
```

The changes in the code's layout were made to support [contexts](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods). For most people this change should have been transparent, but anyone who was importing classes from outside of the top-level package (e.g. `from multiprocessing.queues import Queue` or `from multiprocessing.process import Process`) will see things break on them.

Comment: Unfortunately, it also breaks my development environment, as I use Pydev with Eclipse and it appears that Pydev cannot cope with dynamically constructed __ALL__ and reports failed imports all over the place. For me in this environment multiprocessing.Process no longer works at compile time.

Comment: @Jonathan What do you mean by "no longer works at compile time"? Is your script actually failing to execute with a traceback?

Comment: No, the import of multiprocessing.Process is flagged as not resolved by Pydev.

Comment: @Jonathan I see. I don't know enough about Pydev to tell you if there's something you can do to work around it. All I can say is that `multiprocessing.Process` is still there, so your scripts should still execute ok outside of `Pydev`.